# C# изображение в строку

Tags: c#, изображения, преобразование

Может есть способ более лучше чем этот?

```
//Преобразование изображения в строку
public string ImgToStr(string filename)
{
    MemoryStream Memostr = new MemoryStream();
    Image Img = Image.FromFile(filename);
    Img.Save(Memostr, Img.RawFormat);
    byte[] arrayimg = Memostr.ToArray();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(arrayimg);
}

//Преобразование строки в изображение
public Image StrToImg(string StrImg)
{
    byte[] arrayimg = Convert.FromBase64String(StrImg);
    Image imageStr = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(arrayimg));
    return imageStr;
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам вообще это понадобилось? Строка будет же нечитаемой. Почему просто не использовать `byte[]`?

Comment: зачем так сложно, через поток и открывая именно как изображение -- т.е. ладно бы была проверка существования файла и т.п.
   `public string fileToBase64(string filename)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        }`

Comment: По сути это просто для развития, в приложении картинки выбираются через OpenDialog, а дальше пока не придумал)

Comment: Может в базу данных запихнуть)))